# Ruby programming double a penny a day for period of time

Tags: ruby

I am new, three wekks into Ruby as my first Language. here is the code I already have:

```
=begin
this program is to calculate doubling a penny a day for thirty one days
=end

puts "how many days would you like to calculate"
days = gets.chomp.to_i

i = 1
    loop do
    puts "#{i}"
    break i >=100
end
```

I have tried to use ** as this is they syntax for exponential use. I have considered an until loop also, but the thing I am having most difficulty with is how to double per day each integer for given time.

I have also tried `"#{i**2}"` ,  `"#{i**i}"` , I have tried to google this problem for the past 2 days, to no avail.

Comment: I cant add this to the prior post as it is appantly code that isn't being transmitted,  inside my hash symbols  there are the multilication symbols **

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, the result is just going to be `2^x`, where x is the number of days.

Comment: @Ajedi32 that isn't correct, as you need to add the previous days' output as well.

Comment: @meatspace Could you clarify what you mean? That *does* take the result of previous days into account...

Comment: @Ajedi32 I apologize, I thought this was a compound-interest problem. You are correct.

Comment: You could also do it by induction: `def penny(v=1, count) (count.zero?) ? return v : penny(2*v, count-1) end`. Then `penny(31) => 2147483648`.

Comment: @meatspace, is your interpretation that if `t(n)` is the value on day `n`, then the value on day `n+1` is `t(n)+2*t(n) => 3*t(n)`? If so (and that's not unreasonable), starting with one penny on day zero, the total on day `n` is `t(n) = 3^n`. that's just a compound interest calculation, the interest being 300% per day (ouch!).

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes that's how I read it initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# Display the question to the user in the terminal
puts 'How many days would you like to calculate?'

# Get the number of days from stdin
days = gets.chomp.to_i

# starting at 1 and up to the number of days start doubling. Reduce returns the result back to itself, thus doubling the return of each number until you have reached the up to limit.
result = 1.upto(days).reduce { |start| start * 2 }

# Put the result
puts result
```

Comment: Considering that the OP is brand new to Ruby, some explination as to what's going on here would probably be welcome.

Comment: ok this is working and I like how the code is laid out but please explain the |start| start * 2

Comment: start is the return value of of the last iteration, beginning with 1 for the first iteration. Example: first iteration 'start' is '1' and calculates 1 * 2, thus making the second iteration's 'start' 2 and calculate 2 * 2, thus making the 3rd iterations 'start' 4. calculating 4 * 2.... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using a simple bit shifting operation. Binary value "1" shifted left n times is used to calculate 2^n.

```
puts "how many days would you like to calculate"
days = gets.chomp.to_i
puts 1 << (days - 1)
```

Comment: Probably more efficient than taking a power, but definitely not as readable. I'd avoid doing this unless the particular line of code you're doing this in is performance-critical.

Comment: Just listing all the possible ways to do it :)

Comment: Bravo, Rakesh. Truly Indian solution.

Comment: Trivandrum. There we go. Hey, pal, you are good. What do you do for living?

Comment: I run a software company. We do iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any loop here. What about a power? If you want to double 1 penny in 31 days, you need to calculate 2^30:

```
puts "how many days would you like to calculate"
days = gets.chomp.to_i
puts 2 ** (days - 1)
```

Comment: thank you for posting I will try this, but why the days-1 when I am incrementing up from 1..31

Comment: On day 1 you have 1 penny. On day 2 - 2 pennies (2^1). On day 3 - 4 pennies (2^2). On day 4 - 8 pennies (2^3)... etc

Comment: this works, I think I grok the syntax you are saying, puts  2 ** the exponential symbols for squared (days -1)   but why the days - 1 when I am incrementing from 1..31?

Comment: There is another way to look at this. You could also say that I start with 1 penny (day 0). After 1 day (days = 1), I have 2 pennies. After two days (days = 2), I have 4 pennies, etc. So depending on how you interpret the problem, you could either do `2 ** days` or `2 ** (days - 1)`

Comment: I grok the 2** but why days - 1

Answer (score 0):

```
31.times.reduce 1 do |a| a * 2 end
#=> 2147483648
```

Comment: um this isn't running, is this a line within other code or this is all the code needed to run that calculation?

Comment: What's your Ruby version?

Comment: jcane@linux-ok8d:~> ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i586-linux]